# django filter by related

Tags: django, django-filter

my models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class BankAccount(models.Model):
    iban = models.CharField(max_length=28)
    owners = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='BankAccountPerson')

class BankAccountPerson(models.Model):
    bank_account = models.ForeignKey(BankAccount, on_delete=models.RESTRICT, related_name = 'ownership')
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.RESTRICT, related_name = 'ownership')
    is_owner = models.BooleanField(null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        unique_together= [['bank_account','person']]
```

let's assume, that account no 1 has two owners: person:1 and person:2

And now if I filter like this:

```
person=Person.objects.get(pk=1)
collection = BankAccount.objects.filter(owners=person)
```

will get only one row - with person1.

But I'd like to get two rows: - with both people. Because I want to get accounts with owners, where one of owners is person

I can do it with SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM structure_bankaccount INNER JOIN "structure_bankaccountperson" ON ("structure_bankaccount"."id" = "structure_bankaccountperson"."bank_account_id") WHERE structure_bankaccount.id in (SELECT bank_account_id FROM  "structure_bankaccountperson" WHERE "structure_bankaccountperson"."person_id" = 1)
```

I can do it with two steps:

```
 owned_accounts = BankAccountPerson.objects.filter(person=person).values_list('bank_account_id')
 collection = BankAccount.objects.filter(id__in=owned_accounts)
```

But I wonder if I can do it with some Q, F or other function in one django filter...

Comment: As far as I understand, you want to get duplicated BankAccount objects, like `QuerySet<BankAccount#1, BankAccount#1>`?

Comment: No, I want to get one BankAccount. But with full information about related, because collection = BankAccount.objects.filter(owners=person) has no information about other owners - collection.query has INNER JOIN